# How to get data in InfluxDB subscription end point?

Tags: time-series, influxdb, subscription, influxql, influxdb-2

Hi I have created a subscription (`http`) in the `InfluxDB` using following command :

```
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION "test-data-update" ON "system_managment"."system_managment2d" DESTINATIONS ALL 'http://localhost:9001/ts/data-update'
```

And in the `ExpressJs` app which is running on port `9001` added a route as follows:

```
app.post("/ts/data-update/write", (req, res) => {
    console.log(">>influx data>>");
    console.log(req.body);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

I thought I will be getting all the data in the `req.body` but I am getting nothing in body. How can I get the data through a subscription as mentioned in the [influxdb documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/administration/subscription-management/#create-subscriptions).

> I have seen more examples which is using [`Kapacitor`](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.5/), but as of now we are not planning to us `Kapacitor`.

Let me know how to get the updated data from `InfluxDB` subscription endpoint? Or is it supposed to be like this and we have make normal querying to `InfluxDB` from this endpoint to get data?

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue and the solution is to listen to data event using request object.

```js
app.post("/ts/data-update/write",(req, res) => {
  logger.info('influx data>>');
  logger.info(req.headers);
  logger.info(req.body);
  req.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(chunk.toString());
  });
  req.on('end', () => {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  });
});
```

- Saw header with content length with positive non zero value and did not have value in the request body using express.
- Then I listened using `netcat` on specified port in subscription which hosts a TCP server and had the content at the end.